# C# - Read External CSV File Character by Character

Tags: c#, .net, file, stream

What is the easiest way to read a file character by character in C#?

Currently, I am reading line by line by calling System.io.file.ReadLine(). I see that there is a Read() function but it doesn;t return a character...

I would also like to know how to detect the end of a line using such an approach...The input file in question is a CSV file....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a `TextReader` (e.g. by `File.OpenText` - note that [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) is a static class, so you *can't* create an instance of it) and repeatedly call [`Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w3csw16.aspx). That returns `int` rather than `char` so it can *also* indicate end of file:

```
int readResult = reader.Read();
if (readResult != -1)
{
    char nextChar = (char) readResult;
    // ...
}
```

Or to loop:

```
int readResult;
while ((readResult = reader.Read()) != -1)
{
    char nextChar = (char) readResult;
    // ...
}
```

Or for more funky goodness:

```
public static IEnumerable<char> ReadCharacters(string filename)
{
    using (var reader = File.OpenText(filename))
    {
        int readResult;
        while ((readResult = reader.Read()) != -1)
        {
            yield return (char) readResult;
        }
    }
}

...

foreach (char c in ReadCharacters("foo.txt"))
{
    ...
}
```

Note that all by default, `File.OpenText` will use an encoding of UTF-8. Specify an encoding explicitly if that isn't what you want.

EDIT: To find the end of a line, you'd check whether the character is `\n`... you'd potentially want to handle `\r` specially too, if this is a Windows text file.

But if you want each *line*, why not just call `ReadLine`? You can always iterate over the characters in the line afterwards...

Comment: I assume the OP wants to iterate _all_ characters in the file("_read a file character by character_").

Comment: @TimSchmelter: So they'd need to loop until it returned -1... will edit with more code, but I think this really gives enough information.

Comment: how would i detect the end of a line though?

Comment: @user559142: You'd have to do that yourself, based on line terminators. Your question doesn't mention anything about lines, other than that you *don't* want `ReadLine`. If you want more specific information, ask a more specific question.

Comment: I have added it to my question!

Comment: @user559142: Answer duly edited - but if you're really line-oriented, why don't you just read each line and then examine it?

Comment: I want don't reduce the effect of limitations that could potentially be exhibited by client workstations - in this case memory. The CSV files could potentially be huge and it seemed more efficient to store token by token as oposed to entire lines and then further reprocessing...

Comment: @user559142: Do you really think an *individual line* is going to be of a significant size? Bearing in mind modern memory, are you *really* going to have lines which you think will take more than (say) 1MB of memory? This sounds like a classic example of premature optimization. (Reading 1 line != reading whole file.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.read%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
{
    char[] c = null;

    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        c = new char[1];
        sr.Read(c, 0, c.Length);

        // do something with c[0]
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it's not your code, but it's a horrible approach IMO. Why do this when `Read()` does exactly what's required?